# List unique identifier of missing rows in a series

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to return the row number of missing values within a given series?

```
    Name  Age
    Fred  25
    John  38
    Chris
```

I want to return the row number or some unique identifier of any rows where 'Age' is missing. i.e Chris

Comment: Lets start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learning how to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is the problem with my question?

Comment: You've tried nothing (at least to our knowledge). This would fall into "doing work for you".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `df.index[pd.isnull(df['Age'])]`

Comment: Lonewoolf its better you accept @jezrael's answer. He answered first and both answer are almost same

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [25.0, 38.0, np.nan]}, index=['Fred', 'John', 'Chris'])
print (df)
        Age
Fred   25.0
John   38.0
Chris   NaN

m = df['Age'].isnull()
print (df.index[m].tolist())
[Chris]
```

Comment: Thats very fast one

Comment: Sir set the index as name then use df.index[m.... because OP wants `Chris` as output. OP might have Name as index

Comment: No, becasuse if your answer is accepted `Name` is already index ;0